# PHPでGETの値をSQLに渡すやり方

Tags: php, mysql

現在郵便番号検索サイトを作成しております。
そのなかでGETで取得したデータをもとに次のページ、前のページで遷移できるようにする必要があり、10件ずつデータを表示する必要があります。
次のページ、前のページは完成したのですが、
GETの値をSQLに渡すやり方がいまいちわかりません。
どうすれば渡すことが出来るでしょうか。
参考程度までにソースコード添付いたします。
ご教授お願い致します。
**ソースコード**

```
$post_num = '';
$area ='';
$city ='';
$town ='';
$error1 = [];
$error2 = [];
$user_data = [];
$abc_data = [];
$query = '';
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'codecamp46846';
$passwd   = 'codecamp46846';
$dbname   = 'codecamp46846';
$link= mysqli_connect($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname);
$count = 0;
$page = 1;
/*変数が存在する確認*/ 
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) === true || isset($_POST['submit2']) === true)  {
    if(isset($_POST['post_num']) === true) {
        $post_num = htmlspecialchars($_POST['post_num'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
        if(isset($_POST['area']) === true) {
        $area = htmlspecialchars($_POST['area'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
        if(isset($_POST['city']) === true) {
        $city = htmlspecialchars($_POST['city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
        if(isset($_POST['town']) === true) {
        $town = htmlspecialchars($_POST['town'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
        if(isset($_GET['page']) === true) {
        $page = htmlspecialchars($_POST['page'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
/*空白削除*/
    $post_num = str_replace(array(" ","　"),"", $post_num);
    $area = str_replace(array(" ","　"),"", $area);
    $town = str_replace(array(" ","　"),"", $town);
/*エラーメッセージ*/
    if(empty($post_num) === true && 
    ($area === '都道府県を選択' || empty($city) === true)) {
        $error1[] = '郵便番号を入力してください';
    }else if ((preg_match('/^[0-9]{7}$/', $post_num) !== 1) && 
    ($area === '都道府県を選択' || empty($city) === true)) {
        $error1[] = '７桁の数字で入力してください';
    }else {
        print "";
    }
    if ($area === '都道府県を選択' && 
    (empty($post_num) === true ||(preg_match('/^[0-9]{7}$/', $post_num) !== 1))) {
        $error2[] = '都道府県を選択してください';
    }
    if(empty($city) === true && 
    (empty($post_num) === true ||(preg_match('/^[0-9]{7}$/', $post_num) !== 1))){
        $error2[] = '市区町村名をを入力してください';
    }
/*データベースに接続*/ 
        if(count($error1) === 0 || count($error2) === 0) {
        if($link) {
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table" . (empty($post_num) ? "" : " WHERE post_num = '$post_num'");
            mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
            if(isset($_POST['submit1']) === true) {
                $query = "SELECT post_num, area , city, town FROM test_table 
                WHERE post_num = '$post_num'";
            } else {
                $limit = 10*$page-10;
                $query = "SELECT post_num, area , city, town FROM test_table LIMIT ".$limit.",10";
                $abc = "SELECT post_num, area , city, town FROM test_table";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $abc);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $abc_data[] = $row;
                }
            } 
            // var_dump($query);
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $user_data[] = $row;
                }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($link);
        }else {
            echo 'DB接続失敗';
        }
    }
}
$count = count($abc_data);

if (
  isset($_GET["page"]) &&
  $_GET["page"] > 0 &&
  $_GET["page"] <= 10
) {
  $page = (int)$_GET["page"];
} else {
  $page = 1;
}

$limit = 10*$page-10;
$paging = "SELECT post_num, area , city, town FROM test_table LIMIT ".$limit.",10";
echo $paging;


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>郵便</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="practice_post_code_advanced.php" method="post">
        <h1>郵便番号検索</h1>
        <h2>郵便番号から検索</h2>
        <?php print "総件数" . htmlspecialchars($count,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') . "件";?>
        <input id="post_numer" name="post_num" value="">
        <input type="submit"  name="submit1" value="検索">
        <form action="practice_post_code_advanced.php" method="post">
        <h2>地名から検索</h2>
        <label>都道府県を選択
            <select name="area" value="">
                <option>都道府県を選択</option>
                <option value="北海道">北海道</option>
                <option value="兵庫県">兵庫県</option>
                <option value="新潟県">新潟県</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>市区町村
            <input type="seach" name="city" value="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit2"  value="検索">
        </label>
    </form>
    <p><?php foreach($error1 as $key1 => $string1) {
                print htmlspecialchars($string1,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
            }
    ?></p>
        <p><?php foreach($error2 as $key2 => $string2) {
                print htmlspecialchars($string2,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');;
            }
    ?></p>
        <?php 
    foreach($user_data as $read) {?>
        <table>
           <style type="text/css">
       table, td, th {
           border: solid black 1px;
       }
       table {
           width: 600px;
       }
       tr td {
           width: 150px;
       }
   </style>
            <tr>
                <th>郵便番号</th>
                <th>都道府県</th>
                <th>市町村</th>
                <th>町域</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print htmlspecialchars($read['post_num'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php print htmlspecialchars($read['area'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></td>                
                <td><?php print htmlspecialchars($read['city'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></td>            
                <td><?php print htmlspecialchars($read['town'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></td>          
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php } ?>  
<!-- hyperlink to previous and next page -->
<form name="pagination" action="practice_post_code_advanced.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_num" value="<?php echo $post_num; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="area" value="<?php echo $area; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="town" value="<?php echo $town; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="page">
</form>

<p>
    <?php if ($page > 1) : ?>
      <a href="?page=<?php echo ($paging - 1); ?>">前のページへ</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($page < 10) : ?>
    　　<a href="?page=<?php echo ($paging + 1); ?>">次のページへ</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: こんなのとか？ https://qiita.com/madilloar/items/b4e786a932ef9d4551b9 オイラ個人的には SQL 文を `.` で組み立てている時点で論外です（ SQL インジェクション脆弱性を自ら作りこんでいる）初心者ならばこそ脆弱性の入らない正しい方法（パラメタライズドクエリ）を最初の時点で身につけるべきでしょう。

Comment: ここで質問するのが NG なわけでは決してありませんが、何らかのカリキュラムなりを受けているように見えるので (CodeCamp?)、そちらで質問するのも一つの方法かと思います。

Comment: どのように変えるべきなのでしょうか？

Comment: 本当に分かんなくて困ってます。誰か助けてください

Answer (score 3):

GET か POST かはあまり重要じゃなく、フォームデータを受け取れているのであれば予め定義された変数と変わりなく扱えばよいだけで、受け取ったパラメータ (の変数) を適切な形でクエリに組み込むだけではないでしょうか？

---

質問のコードに当てはめると…

- `$_GET['page']` でパラメータは受け取れており、扱いやすいよう適当な変数に入れ直す等して
- クエリを組み立てている部分に変数を埋め込む (以下のコードは原文ママ)

```php
/*データベースに接続*/ 
if(count($error1) === 0 || count($error2) === 0) {
    if($link) {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table" . (empty($post_num) ? "" : " WHERE post_num = '$post_num'");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。試しにやってみます

Comment: わからないので具体的にどうすればいいか教えてください

Comment: この回答でご自身でソースを改修してみて、何がうまくいかなかったか質問に追記すればより細かい回答がもらえるでしょう。この回答はソースは出ていないものの、十分これをもとに改修はできる内容だと思います。

Comment: 色々試したらうまくいけました。ありがとうございます。